# Bootstrap icons not showing with font disable in IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, glyphicons

My client has IE8 or IE11 with a lot of security configuration. They have the font download option disabled and that makes the bootstrap icons to not show up. Is there anyway to make them appear?

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap icons are imported via CSS like this:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);
    src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
    url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
    url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff) format('woff'),
    url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) format('truetype'),
    url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular) format('svg')}
```

Instead you can use a [URI Generator](http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php) to convert the files into a data string value.

This will allow you to use the font icons without having to import the files

Comment: but if I have those files in my project they should be displayed, shouldn't they?

Comment: But IE 11 is so stubborn that, even when the font is embedded in a data string, it prevents/ask for additional font download.